# Meteor Testing - Client tests not running under dispatch:mocha-phantomjs

Tags: meteor, mocha.js

My tests are written in mocha and they work fine when I invoke the tests using practical meteor like so:

```
meteor test --full-app --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha --port 4000 --settings test_settings.json
```

But when I try to use dispatch:mocha-phantomjs, only the server side tests run:

```
meteor test --once --full-app --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs --settings test_settings.json
```

Am I just missing something about the separation of meteor client and server?

I am trying to use Travis for CI so I need to switch my tests over to the command line output rather than browser

From my meteor/versions

```
dispatch:mocha-phantomjs@0.1.6
dispatch:phantomjs-tests@0.0.5
practicalmeteor:chai@2.1.0_1
practicalmeteor:loglevel@1.2.0_2
practicalmeteor:mocha@2.4.5_3
practicalmeteor:mocha-core@1.0.1
practicalmeteor:sinon@1.14.1_2
```

I am using the 2.4.5 rc3 of practical meteor because of a bug that appears when dispatch and practical meteor exist in the same package file

Thanks!

Comment: where do you put your test files

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using spacejam/practicalmeteor:mocha-console-runner to get my client tests to run in travis. I am posting my .travis.yml for anyone interested.

```
sudo: true

language: node_js

before_install:
- npm install -g spacejam
- echo $METEOR_SETTINGS > test_settings.json
# assumes that meteor is not installed
# - curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
# if meteor has been properly cached
- sudo ln -s $HOME/.meteor/meteor /usr/local/bin/meteor

cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
    - $HOME/.meteor/

before_script:
  - meteor npm install

script:
  - spacejam test --full-app --once --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha-console-runner --settings test_settings.json
```